# Ignoring non-specified points in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, label

how can we ignore the non-specified values in x-axis label of a matlab plot?

for ex:
if my

`x=[201:210];,y=rand(size(x));`

I would like to display only those specified values of x such as 201,202,203..instead of with the intermediate values such as 201.5,202.5.. Basically I wanna get rid of these decimal values in my plot.

thanks in advance.
DURAI

Comment: My answer is quite lengthy because your title, doesn't match with the first sentence of your question. But at the end you are asking the same as the title... Not sure which part of my answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to plot them. You can just specify your variables used in plot.

```
plot(x(1:2:end),y(1:2:end))
```

this would plot only each second value. Obviously you can use logical indexing and any other means e.g. another index-array as well.

```
plot(x(x>10),y(x>10))
```

as another example. Just take care that you use the same commands in both variables otherwise you will get wrong results or an error (if number of points don't match up).

If you want to plot specific values you can use a for loop to loop over the values you want to use:

```
x=1:1:10;
y=115:15:250;

figure(2)
for x=[4,5,7]
    display(x)
    plot(x,y(x),'x'); hold on
end
```

If you want to just change the area which is displayed but use the whole set of data points you can use:

```
axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
```

or if you want to change the labels of x-axis use:

```
set(gca, 'XTick',new_x_axis_steps, 'XTickLabel',new_x_labels(new_x_axis_steps))
```

where new_x_axis_steps is an array which defines the start, end point and the step and new_x_labels is what you want to write there (if you want to use strings), otherwise just use:

```
set(gca, 'XTick',new_x_axis_steps)
```